# How can you split a list to another list if it contains a certain value?

Tags: java

I have a list of values in my controller that it obtained from another class. The list contains the values of "Status". Status has different values stored into it such as, Ok, Bad, CRITICAL. I am trying to extract the values of each. IF list value "status" contains OK, put it into a OKlist, same with the others. Below is my code snippet and What I did alternatively.

**Class snippet**

```
public class Album implements Runnable {        
    //doing many stuff then 
    memoryUtilization = 100 - memoryUtilization; 
        if (memoryUtilization <= badThreshold
                    && memoryUtilization > criticalThreshold) {
        Status = "BAD";

            }else if (memoryUtilization <= criticalThreshold) {
                Status = "CRITICAL";

            }
            else {
                Status = "OK";

            }

            data.add(new AlbumModel (Status));
```

**Controller snippet**

```
    @Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private AlbumList albumL;

    public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {

List<AlbumModel> list = albumL.getList();
System.out.println(list);
```

**OutPut**

```
[Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: OK,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: BAD,Status: CRITICAL,Status: CRITICAL,Status: CRITICAL,Status: CRITICAL,Status: CRITICAL,Status: CRITICAL]
```

**Attempt**

In the class where I determine weather the status is bad,crit, or ok, I created List values for each status, then I added the values into the list in the IF statement where it determines the status value.

**Class**

```
public class Album implements Runnable {  
static List<AlbumModel> data = new ArrayList<AlbumModel>();
static List<AlbumModel> criticalList = new ArrayList<AlbumModel>(); 
static List<AlbumModel> badList = new ArrayList<AlbumModel>(); 
static List<AlbumModel> okList = new ArrayList<AlbumModel>(); 
 //getters and setters      
    /**************doing many stuff ****************/
    memoryUtilization = 100 - memoryUtilization; 
        if (memoryUtilization <= badThreshold
                    && memoryUtilization > criticalThreshold) {

        Status = "BAD";
                badList.add(new AlbumModel (Status));
            }else if (memoryUtilization <= criticalThreshold) {

                Status = "CRITICAL";
                criticalList.add(new AlbumModel (Status));
            }
            else {
                Status = "OK";
                okList.add(new AlbumModel (Status));
            }

            data.add(new AlbumModel (Status));
```

Then in my controller class I just called the class in to retrieve the values. Would this be the right way to resolve my question?

**Index Controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private AlbumList albumL;    
    public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {
List<AlbumModel> list = albumL.getList();      
List<AlbumModel> albumCritList = Album.getCritList();
List<AlbumModel> albumBadList = Album.getBadList();
List<AlbumModel> albumOkList = Album.getOkList();
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: You want to split list or add the whole list to one of those three?

Comment: how did you try with pseudo code?

Comment: @Taelsin the Script above is what I tried, I think I have the logic down I just need to know how to write the correct syntax.

Comment: @Akceptor I want to split the list into 3 different list.

Comment: If you're still fighting with Java syntax, to the point that you can't even try something, why are you dealing with Spring-based web applications? You should practice with hello-world-like exercises first. Read your text book, read the javadoc, and try somthing.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry if this post offended you. I am new to spring boot and java. Learning them both simultaneously.

Comment: I'm not offended. And everybody has to start somewhere. But trying to use Spring boot when you don't know the basics of Java syntax is like trying to fly a Boeing 747 when you don't know what "north" and "south" mean.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you provide me some advice on how I can improve my post?

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, something like this:

```
final List<AlbumModel> critcalList =
        originalList.filter(albumModel -> "CRITICAL".equals(albumModel.getFoo()))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(new LinkedList<AlbumModel>());
```

// Rinse and repeat for other lists